# I Need assistance with a WordPress custom delete link?

Tags: php, wordpress

So what I am trying to do I am trying to make a WordPress plugin to allow me to simply add a Delete Link By ID function. I can not find a code to customize and I have no clue how to make one from scratch. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? I tried all the stuff I Could find on the web nothing worked when I customized it sadly. This plugin I am making is Free. You can download right now on WordPress. Its made by the community with there ideas and mine. Can someone please help a novice out thanks. Here is part of my code so you guys get an idea what it is and may need it for the function.

```
<?php
}

function ryv_adminpage(){
  global $wpdb;

  if($_POST['ryv_submit']){
    $leeren = $wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `".$wpdb->prefix."randomyoutube`");

    if($_POST['url']){
      foreach($_POST['url'] as $key => $con){
        if($con){
          $ins = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `".$wpdb->prefix."randomyoutube` (`id`,`url`,`vtitle`) VALUES (".$key.",'".$con."','".$_POST['vtitle'][$key]."')");
        }
      }

      $message = '<div class="updated"><p><strong>Saved.</strong></p></div>';
    }
  }?>
<a href="index.php?delete=<?$post['id']);?>" onClick="return confirmDelete();">Delete</a>
```

The link is how I want it to show up as. I know its possible and this is what always stumps me the simple stuff. Not sure what but it does. If anyone is kind enough to help you will be credited in the plugin page. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you posting multiple inputs with the same name as array and the database id as the id? When you post anything with `$_POST['ryv_submit']` are you sure you want to delete everything in the `wp_randomyoutube` table? Also, you said you want to delete but you are inserting?

Comment: Is the id numeric? Does it have auto increment? I think you need to post the whole code or it is quite hard to guess what's going on. Also, you need to prepare your query, example: `https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb`

Comment: @peixotorms I was hoping to delete just the id in that row. I don't wanna delete all the videos since users would be sorta upset lol. I am still searching for an option. Thanks guys for your help.